# How to add a Google Reviews Widget to Website

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

How to add a Google Reviews "Add a Review" widget to website. I would like to avoid people from going away from my website.

The below page will pop up when you click on the link. http://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJZWeEOpbyUjoRkIublNLBZ-k.

I have seen some websites showing a direct iframe of the following image in their website. Is this a paid service from Google?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is just a url to send users directly to the reviews form. There are many websites out there that can generate that kind of link for you automatically either using your business name directly or by having you first find the business on Google search/maps and provide some type of ID.

Here's a relevant Google search where you can find those review link generators: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+reviews+link+generator&oq=google+reviews+link+genera&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60l2j0j69i64.4709j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

All of those generators, and the link provided by Google for users to create reviews, are free.

Comment: This is fine. I am more  looking into embedding the above page directly into my application